# Is my public IP really unique?

Tags: networking, ip, router, nat, telecommunication

I'm asking about if the IP address of my router (my "public" IP address) is actually unique, i.e. it is not shared with other routers/hosts over the Internet.

If it is the case, I imagine that there will be some NAT policies applied by my ISP, which translates my "public" IP address and the port of my connection in some other IP:port pair (just like happens in local NAT).

Comment: Except in the case of anycast, public IP addresses are unique, although what the ISP assigns you may not be a public address. See CGN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many operators use a version of NAT which is called by several names: Carrier Grade NAT, NAT 44, Large Scale NAT.

Essentially the operators use private addressing between the network core and the edge devices (i.e. your router) and then translate the private addresses to public addresses at the core of their network before traffic goes to another network.

There is not a one to one mapping between the private addresses and the public addresses, and even port numbers can be reused over time.

So to identify a given private address and hence user from the operator logs, you need to look at the public IP address, the public port and the timestamp (as the same public IP and port may be mapped to a different private IP at a different time).

Things start to get even more complex when you try to make the network devices as optimised as possible - there are mechanisms to try to assign to same public IP and port to a private IP that it has used previously for efficiency. This can give the impression to an end device that it has a static IP mapping in the NAT, but often this is not actually the case.

Finally, all the above is independent of any locate NAT you may have in your home or business - i.e. you can and probably will have a NAT translation on you local router for your locals devices also.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike IP addresses, public IP addresses are not used in a local network but only on the internet. The routers (iphone: your box) IP address to internet, it that rent your box visible on the internet (it will respond to the ping). But also, when you use a website you use the public address of the web server.

A public IP address is unique in the world, which is not the case for private addresses which must be unique in the same local network but not at the global level since these addresses can not be routed on the internet.

Public IP addresses that list all IP addresses of classes A, B, and C that are part of the list of private addresses for those classes or class A exceptions.

Comment: "_Unlike IP addresses, public IP addresses are not used in a local network but only on the internet._" That simply is not true. Many, many businesses and governments own blocks of public IP addresses, and they use them on their networks. Also, network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking has not used classes for more than 20 years now. Please let them rest in peace.